# Is wget a default in Windows, if not what download function is available by default

Tags: windows, batch-file, wget

I made many changes to my machine so not sure if wget is available as a result of my changes or it always exists by default on Windows machines. Does it come with Windows

If not, what download function can I use in a Windows .bat script to download a file from the web. This function has to be available by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wget is not built into windows, however there is a windows version.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

As far as I am aware, there is no similar built in dos command for windows.

Answer (score 4):

Although wget is not built into Windows, BITSAdmin.exe is (in Vista/7/2008) and can download files from the web:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362812(v=vs.85).aspx

Since BITSAdmin is not as fully featured as wget, I typically use it just to bootstrap installing wget on the machine with the following command:

**bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority high http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/cgi-bin/fetch.pl?dl=wget/wget.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\wget.exe**

Then I can run wget for any additional downloading.

Answer (score 1):

wget does not come with windows. In the past I've usually downloaded it from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).